# Generate a Image like Object using CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am looking at generating the below image using CSS.

I've tried adding all the required information needed below.

The BgColor, Font-Color, Font Size, Font Family, Font Style. Please mention if any  other data is needed.

The Font Text should be displayed in the middle of the image. How do I build CSS to get the text in the centre.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown us what you've already tried. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: You should ask me what I've tried, rather that down voting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>WW</div>
```

CSS

```
div{ background:#ced6e9;
font:bold 46px arial; color:#315bb4;
width:100px; height:100px; line-height:100px;text-align:center}
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9Dxza/1/

Answer (score 1):

horizontal centering:

```
text-align : center;
```

vertical centering:

```
line-height : 100px;
```

Comment: I don't know why, but anyways upvoted cuz its correct

Comment: Sorry, that was an accidental click by me! Removed. Although I don't think this question should have been answered as OP hasn't actually attempted anything and this looks like a homework question.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Bad accident, that usually happens when I am using my phone..

Comment: @JamesDonnelly -- Perhaps, but OP just asked how to center text which is, I think, a valid question.  I didn't answer the rest of it (how to create the 100x100px div, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color: green;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
```